# Correct JSON to POST to PubSub - Dataflow - BiqQuery? Correct dataschema?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm taking my first experimental steps with google-pre-setup templates in a Google Cloud Template (Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery).

As a milestone to my final goal (having physical gadgets reporting a data stream to Google Cloud Pub/Bub), my wish is to achieve something like this:

POSTMAN (make authenticated POST request with JSON message to an Google Cloud Platform, GPC,  endpoint) -->  GPC Pub/Sub --> GPC DataFlow --> GPC BigQuery.

Right now I am following the tutorial found in Executing Templates, https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/executing-templates, "Example 2: Custom template, streaming job". This section states:

> ...This example projects.templates.launch request creates a streaming job
>   from a template that reads from a Pub/Sub topic and writes to a
>   BigQuery table. ***The BigQuery table must already exist with the
>   appropriate schema.*** If successful, the response body contains an
>   instance of LaunchTemplateResponse. ...

and further more how to do a POST:

`https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/templates/TemplateName`

```
{
    "jobName": "[JOB_NAME]",
    "parameters": {
        "topic": "projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/topics/[YOUR_TOPIC_NAME]",
        "table": "[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]:[YOUR_DATASET].[YOUR_TABLE_NAME]"
    },
    "environment": {
        "tempLocation": "gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/temp",
        "zone": "us-central1-f"
    }
}
```

There are two things that confuses me. Let's for the sake of a simple example say that I have multiple vehicles who continuously should report their current status. I have already created my MQTT topic: **VEHICLE_STATUS**. Each och my vehicles should be able to report its:

- Position [String]
- Speed [Float]
- Time [String]
- VehicleID [Integer]

=======

I'm aware of the prototype for a [PubsubMessage](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage):

```
{
  "data": string,
  "attributes": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "messageId": string,
  "publishTime": string,
}
```

**My questions:**

1. How should my BigQuery table schema look (which columns do I need to create)?
2. How should the entire corresponding JSON message look? What should my vehicle report to the endpoint each time?